# Excel formulas for budgeting sheet (or VBA code)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm (an amateur) and I'm creating a sheet to help me with Budgeting.  I've got bills that I can enter, but that come at a variety of different intervals.   I'd love it if I could enter the total from the bill into one cell in a row, and have excel workout the amount for all the other intervals (four other cells in the row).

I known how to write formulas into a cell so that the another cell in the row will populate correctly (=sum(B3/52)  but don't know how to use 'or' so that the formula knows to look in one of four other cells to find a value to use... would it take VBA to do that?

Id post an example..  but I need a ranking here to do that.  Column headings are intervals i.e. Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Annually

Im using excel 2010.

Thanks for any Help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel - how to either have direct data input or cell value from formula](http://superuser.com/questions/649311/excel-how-to-either-have-direct-data-input-or-cell-value-from-formula)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is asking a different question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to enter a bill's amount in one cell which may be a weekly, monthly, quarterly or annual amount and, based on the actual interval of each bill, calculate the amount for all other intervals.

One way to do it is is to use a series of nested IF statements.

Set up your spreadsheet as outlined below:

Label columns A-F as follows:

- A = Interval
- B = Amount
- C = Weekly
- D = Monthly
- E = Quarterly
- F = Annually

In subsequent row, place a code in column A to indicate the actual interval of your bill:

- W for Weekly
- M for Monthly
- Q for Quarterly
- A for Annually

Place actual bill amount in Column B.

Put formulas below in Columns C through F:

Formula for Cell C2:

```
=IF(A2="W",B2,(IF(A2="M",B2/4,(IF(A2="Q",B2/12,IF(A2="A",B2/52,""))))))
```

Formula for Cell D2:

```
=IF(A2="W",B2*4,(IF(A2="M",B2,(IF(A2="Q",B2/3,IF(A2="A",B2/12,""))))))
```

Formula for Cell E2:

```
=IF(A2="W",B2*12,(IF(A2="M",B2*3,IF(A2="Q",B2,IF(A2="A",B2/4,""))))))
```

Formula for Cell F2:

```
=IF(A2="W",B2*52,(IF(A2="M",B2*12,(IF(A2="Q",B2*4,IF(A2="A",B2,""))))))
```

Note that these formulas assume you are using columns A-F.  If you are putting this in another part of your spreadsheet, you have to adjust accordingly.

They also assume 4 weeks to a month, 12 weeks to a quarter, 3 months to a quarter, and 52 weeks to a year.

I think I got the calculations right, but it's always possible there's a typo.  The logic of the syntax, however, is correct.

Once the formulas are entered in one row, you can copy them to as many other rows as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Elaine & Ben, my Sheet = fantastic!  I would never have come up with that.  I changed the formula just slightly to make the calculations more accurate...  I used this:  

Weekly=IF(D16="W",C16,(IF(D16="M",C16/30.416*7,(IF(D16="Q",C16/91.25*7,IF(D16="A",C16/52,IF(D16="F",C16/2,"")))))))

Fortnightly=IF(D16="W",C16*2,(IF(D16="M",C16/30.416*14,(IF(D16="Q",C16/91.25*14,IF(D16="A",C16/26,IF(D16="F",C16,"")))))))
e.c.t.   
I also learnt careful use of the escape key !!    Cheers !