# RE: displaying max of direct data input or cell value from formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

With reference to :
[Excel - how to either have direct data input or cell value from formula](https://superuser.com/questions/649311/excel-how-to-either-have-direct-data-input-or-cell-value-from-formula)

I would like to inquire on a related issue.
How would i edit my VBA formula if i would like to compare the existing formulated value, with the new input value. And display the Max of both the formulated and the newer input value.

Thank you very much for your kind assistance.
Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your original request: If A2 and A3 both have numeric values, then A4 will be populated with their sum. If they are non-numeric or null then A4 will show an error. If A4 is overwritten then that value will be permanent until A2 or A3 are changed again. To add the new requirements: If A2 and A3 produced a good sum for A4 and someone overwrites A4 with a new numeric value, then you wish the max to be taken between A2+A3 and A4. I assume this should be displayed in cell A5.

Adding to the original answer:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A3")) Is Nothing Then
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A2:A3")) = 2 Then
        Range("A4").Formula = "=A2+A3"
    End If
ElseIf Not (Intersect(Target, Range("A4"))) Is Nothing Then
    'Check for numbers in a2, a3, and a4
    If IsNumeric(Range("A2").Value) And IsNumeric(Range("A3").Value) And IsNumeric(Range("A4").Value) Then
        'If a2+a3 is greater than a4
        If Range("A2").Value + Range("A3").Value > Range("A4").Value Then
            'set the sum of a2 and a3 to cell a5
            Range("A5").Value = Range("A2").Value + Range("A3").Value
        Else
            'set the value of cell a4 to cell a5
            Range("A5").Value = Range("A4").Value
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub`