# Excel - user input but retain formula for two circular cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make two cells retain background formula after user input and has a circular formula.

```
A1 = Lbs
A2 = Kgs

Formula
A1 = A2*2.2
A2 = A1/2.2
```

I know about the thread below but I cannot get this to work for circular formulas.
I have enabled use iterative calculation in preference.
[Excel - how to either have direct data input or cell value from formula](https://superuser.com/questions/649311/excel-how-to-either-have-direct-data-input-or-cell-value-from-formula/1222690#1222690)

Answer (score 6):

Excel does not work like this.

If both cells have formulas then there is nowhere to get an input value from. That's why this will not work with circular references.

A cell can either have a formula or a value. If you enter a value into a cell that has a formula, the formula will be overwritten. What you are trying to achieve will require at least 3 cells: an entry cell for the value, a cell for the unit and a third cell for the conversion result. You may even want to add a fourth cell for the unit of the result. Consider this screenshot:

The Value is entered in B2, the unit of the value is specified in C2. The conversion is calculated in B3

```
=IF(C2="lbs",B2/2.2,B2*2.2)
```

The unit of the result is calculated in C3 with `=IF(C2="Kgs","Lbs","Kgs")`, but that bit is optional.

[image]

Edit: You can use VBA to convert the value and place it in the other cell. This can be done without writing a formula into the cell, though. If you already use VBA, you might as well do the calculation in VBA instead of using VBA to write a formula into a cell. Here is the VBA for that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Row = 1 Then
            Target.Offset(1, 0) = Target / 2.2
        Else
            Target.Offset(-1, 0) = Target * 2.2
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End If
End Sub
```