# Two related cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc, cells

In A1 I have price, for example 1000. In A2 fill percentage, for example 10%. Then in B2, calculate A1*A2 = value. I would like when i fill percentage in A2, in B2 calculate value and vice versa - If I fill the value in B2, to calculate percentage in A2.
How can I do that for LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: You can't. A cell can contain _either_ a value _or_ a formula, not both. The best you can do is to have new row, where `C1` and `C2` contain the percentage and absolute value, using `ISBLANK()` to check which of `B1` or `B2` is set.

Comment: @AFH , I like your solution, but it's possible to [accomplish it with only A1:B2](https://superuser.com/questions/649311/excel-how-to-either-have-direct-data-input-or-cell-value-from-formula)

Comment: @davidmneedham - Your link is implemented in VBA, which is not supported in LibreOffice.

Comment: @AFH , that's true. I'm not familiar with the scripting language in LibreOffice, but I imagine it could be implemented within LibreOffice as well.

Comment: @davidmneedham - LO supports a number of scripting languages, but I am not sufficiently conversant in their integration with LO to be able to say if the VBA solution can be implemented.

Comment: It would not be too hard to write such a macro, but it seems a waste since LO already has a tool for this, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After entering `=A1*A2` in cell B2, go to *Tools -> Solver*.

- Target cell `B2`
- Optimize result to, Value of, `250` (for example)
- By changing cells `A2`

Then press *Solve*.  Cell A2 will change to 25%.

[image: solver]